# How do I keep a user input? (php)

Tags: php, html, input, comments

So I want to make an online journal thing but I am having one problem that I haven't figured out. So the user fills out a form with there comment, and       then presses post. The php is:

```
$comment = $_POST["comment"];

print "$comment";
```

When they press post, it displays there previously written text. But, when they type in a new thing, it just replaces the old text. how do I make it so they both stay?

Comment: By storing the old text in either a session or a cooki or write it to a db

Comment: Do you have a database set up? What type of setup do you want? Something being stored forever or just something being displayed for only a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store previous value on temporary basis then you can use session. Just store all values in session.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Secondaly, if you want to store it permanent, then you better look into `MySQL` or similar database.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Let us know exactly what you want, so, we can give you more specific answer.